# inline svg: make image width fit its content

Tags: html, svg

Consider the code below. Am I able to make the two inline svg's fit their respective text content? I.e. "Teststring. Lorem." should be longer and "foo" shorter. I need two identical svg's with the content text being the only difference. Currently they have a static width of 50px.

I know that I could achieve this easily via HTML+CSS, but in my real world scenario I need SMIL animations behind a text and this is the easiest way to do it. I already have (more complicated) alternatives, so that is not what I want. I just want to know if this is possible and if so how. So "it cannot work at all, try something different" would be a valid answer. (Although not something I hope for.)

```html
<svg width="50" height="20" viewBox="0 0 50 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20">
  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   Teststring. Lorem.
  </body>
 </foreignObject>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.3)"></rect>
</svg><br>

<svg width="50" height="20" viewBox="0 0 50 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20">
  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   foo
  </body>
 </foreignObject>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.3)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the following is the right way to do this, but it works.

## Explanation of the solution

The text inside the svg is wrapped in a span tag. In the onload event the width of the svg tag is set to the width of that span element that is measured via javascript. Unfortunately you have to set an individual id for the svg tag and adjust the id string in the first line of the javascript code accordingly.

## Setting the new width

Also you need to set the new width to all relevant elements in the svg. Which could become a bit ugly if you have lots of elements.
A possible shortcut could be a group element whose transform attribute is manipulated. This would scale the group's content to the correct size while preserving the propertions. Something like the following:

```
//javascript
thisSvg.getElementsByClassName('group')[0].setAttribute(
    'transform', 'scale('+textWidth/50+')');

<!--svg-->
<g class="group">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.3)"></rect>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="25" height="20" fill="rgba(1,0,0,.3)"></rect>
</g>
```

## The actual solution

```html
<svg id="custom-id-1" width="50" height="20" viewBox="0 0 50 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" onload="
  var thisSvg = document.getElementById('custom-id-1');
  var box = thisSvg.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  var textWidth = box.right-box.left;
  thisSvg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 '+textWidth+' 20');
  thisSvg.setAttribute('width', textWidth);
  thisSvg.getElementsByClassName('foreign')[0].setAttribute('width', textWidth);
  thisSvg.getElementsByClassName('rect')[0].setAttribute('width', textWidth);
">
 <foreignObject class="foreign" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20">
  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <span class="text" style="white-space:nowrap">Teststring. Lorem.</span>
  </body>
 </foreignObject>
 <rect class="rect" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.3)"></rect>
</svg><br>

<svg id="custom-id-2" width="50" height="20" viewBox="0 0 50 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" onload="
  var thisSvg = document.getElementById('custom-id-2');
  var box = thisSvg.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  var textWidth = box.right-box.left;
  thisSvg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 '+textWidth+' 20');
  thisSvg.setAttribute('width', textWidth);
  thisSvg.getElementsByClassName('foreign')[0].setAttribute('width', textWidth);
  thisSvg.getElementsByClassName('rect')[0].setAttribute('width', textWidth);
">
 <foreignObject class="foreign" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20">
  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <span class="text" style="white-space:nowrap">foo</span>
  </body>
 </foreignObject>
 <rect class="rect" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.3)"></rect>
</svg>
```